# Writing 0's to a binary file C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

I want to write a series of 0's to a binary file.  As a char, this should be a space, however, I am receiving many other odd characters when I write to my file.  I am not writing zeroes but something else it seems.

Am I doing this correctly?

Code:

```
int zero = 0;
myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&zero),1790*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: You should really get an introductory book on C/C++ and study it. You have a pretty fundamental problem here.

Comment: First, get your story straight!  You have uppercase letter O, and then you say it's a char (i.e. character), and then it's a space (which is ASCII 32).

Comment: Several things are amiss, here: 1. You should not need reinterpret_cast to solve this problem. 2. You are not calling `write()` correctly. 3. You don't seem to be clear on the difference between 0, 'O', and the space character. 4. You need to learn about pointers some more. But you can do it - just get to some learning (:

Comment: `head -c 1790 /dev/zero > myfile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1790; ++i)
{
    char zero = 0;
    myfile.write(&zero, sizeof(char));
}
```

Your code writes 1790 bytes but `zero` is only four bytes big, so you end up writing random garbage.

Another way would be

```
char zero[1790] = { 0 };
myfile.write(zero, sizeof zero);
```

The point is that when you use `write` the size of the first argument to write must be at least as big as the value of the second argument to write.

Answer (score 6):

You are writing 1790 bytes of random memory starting at address `&zero`. First 4 bytes of that memory will be zeroes (value of `zero` assuming `sizeof(int)==4`), the rest is probably not.

Comment: Technically, the behaviour is undefined (not random, or even anything - it could segfault instead, for example).

Comment: It's much worse than "random memory".